# Notifying a waiting thread on changing a variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I am struggling to understand the usage of wait(), notify() and synchronized methods in general. I have this following example where it doesn´t work. Some other object invokes `dataHasChanged()`, which changes the value of the instance variable `datachanged` to `true`. Then, with `notifyAll()`, the waiting Thread checks the value of `datachanged`. So far, so good. But: the value of `datachanged` is `false` when checked in `while(!datachanged)`. So, I assume, `datachanged = true` is somehow not registering with my Refresher-Object. What am I doing wrong?

```
public synchronized  void dataHasChanged(){
    datachanged = true;
    notifyAll();
}

class Refresher extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{

    public synchronized void refresh(){
        while(!datachanged){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            }
        }
        setRights();
        datachanged = false;            
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        refresh();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        refresher = new Refresher();
        refresher.execute();
    }


}
```

Comment: Note that the `notifyAll()` is called on `this`. In your `dataHasChanged()` that is a different object than in your `refresh()`. Also, consider making `datachanged` `volatile`.

Comment: How many threads do you have running (using function refresh()) and how did you define "datachanged"?

Comment: @Andreas M. There is only one Refresher-Thread running per instance of the outer class. datachanged is private volatile Boolean.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis so, if I get this right, I should consider moving datachanged from the outer to the inner class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wait(), notify(), notifyAll()` and synchronize operate per object. In your case refresh() waits on an instance of Refresh and `notifyAll()` notifies all objects waiting on an instance of your outer class. For this to work both wait() and `notifyAll()` have to be called on the same object (so has synchronized()).

The following performs all operations on the instance of your outer class.

```
 public void refresh(){
    synchronized(WhateverYourOuterClass.this){
        while(!datachanged){
            try {
                WhateverYourOuterClass.this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            }
        }
        setRights();
        datachanged = false;            
    }
}
```